# perl file to hex number 82?

Tags: file, perl, hex

Trying to do binary to hex conversion on a file. I can output the hex but however when I try to output the result to a file,variable it returns the string "82".  I cannot understand why; like all things most likely something simple.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $blockSize = 1024;
my $fileName = $ARGV[0];
my $hexName = $ARGV[1];
open(F,"<$fileName") or die("Unable to open file $fileName, $!");
binmode(F);
my $buf;
my $ct=0;

while(read(F,$buf,$blockSize,$ct*$blockSize)){
    foreach(split(//, $buf)){
    printf unpack ("H*", $_);    #prints the hex stream to terminal just fine
    open(H,">$hexName") or die("Unable to open file $fname, $!");
    binmode (H);
        printf H unpack ("H*", $_);
    close (H);

    }
    print "\n";
    $ct++;
}
close(F);
```

**Output**

```
perl rawrHexFile.pl test.png file.hex
89504e470d0a1a0a0000000....
```

mookie@temple:/srv/bench % cat file.hex
82

```
cat file.hex
82
```

Thanks.

**Here's my final code which works. in case of**

```
use strict;
my $fileName = $ARGV[0];
my $hexName = $ARGV[1];
my $hexCodeFile = $ARGV[2];
my $hexDecodeFile = $ARGV[3];
my $blockSize = -s $fileName;
my $buf;

open(F,"<$fileName") or die("Unable to open file $fileName, $!");
binmode(F);

open(H,">$hexName") or die("Unable to open file $hexName, $!");
read(F,$buf,$blockSize);
        print H unpack ("H*", $buf);
close (H);
close(F);
```

Comment: First of all, the program doesn't even compile, so it doesn't give you the output you claim it does.

Comment: You recreate the file (`open >`) for each byte of the input file, so you only get the output for the last byte of the input file. Open the file outside of the loop

Comment: Also, you keep appending to what you've previously read and processing the entire buffer from the start, so your output will look like AABABCABCDABCDE instead of the desired ABCDE (where each letter represents the output for 1024 bytes of input).

Comment: Lots of other issues (2-arg open, `printf` without a pattern, needless use of global vars, needlessly splitting the input when `unpack H*` handles strings of any length, 1 KiB `read` when Perl reads from the OS in 4 KiB or 8 KiB chunks, use of `binmode` for a text file)

Comment: Congrats on checking the result of `open`, and on using both the file name and `$!` in the error message.

Comment: now it works. Cheers! - I've swapped blockSize to use "-s $fileName" to auto determine the file length and tidied up with your comments. It now works writing hex to file. Thank you.

Comment: Poor solution. It introduces a race condition and needless limitations. Moving the `open` as I suggested is what you should have done.

Comment: I did move the open from the foreach loop t into the while. Please see the amended update and recomment? When I moved the file it was only populating the file with 1024 worth of bytes. As the $blocksize is required for the syntax right? Syntax read FILEHANDLE,SCALAR,LENGTH

Answer (score 2):

You recreate the file (open >) for each byte of the input file, so you only get the output for the last byte of the input file. Open the file outside of the loop.

Also, you keep appending to `$buf` rather than replacing its content, so your output will look like AABABCABCDABCDE instead of the desired ABCDE (where each letter represents the output for 1024 bytes of input)

Fixed:

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

use constant BLOCK_SIZE => 64*1024;

my ($in_qfn, $out_qfn) = @ARGS;

open(my $in_fh, '<:raw', $in_qfn)
   or die("Unable to open \"$in_qfn\": $!\n");
open(my $out_fh, '>', $out_qfn)
   or die("Unable to open \"$out_qfn\": $!\n");

while (1) {
    defined( my $rv = sysread($in_fh, my $buf, BLOCK_SIZE) )
       or die("Unable to read from \"$in_qfn\": $!\n");

    last if !$rv;

    print($fh_out unpack("H*", $buf))
       or die("Unable to write to \"$out_qfn\": $!\n");
}

close($fh_in);
close($fh_out)
   or die("Unable to write to \"$out_qfn\": $!\n");
```

The above addressed a lot of other issues in your program:

- Use of 2-arg open
- Use of printf without a pattern
- Needless use of global vars
- Needlessly splitting the input when `unpack H*` handles strings of any length
- Inefficient 1 KiB reads when Perl reads from the OS in 4 KiB or 8 KiB chunks
- Use of binmode for a text file